# Where we have to use only register variable?

Tags: c, variables, compiler-construction, storage, cpu-registers

As we know the `register variable` is `faster accessible` and it is upon the `compiler` to create any variable of `register variable`.

```
register int val;
```

I just want to know "Is there any situation/application ***where we have to only use `register variable`*** and other variable is not useful on such cases?"

If you can put a piece of code it is good to understand.

Comment: Even when you use the keyword `register` a compiler is free to ignore you.

Comment: Ans: After reading some tutorials i found there is no situation where we only use `register` variables, because there is no guarantee from compiler whether my variable would be register type or not. Advantage of this will be- this variable is not `<optimized out>` but an auto variable would be if not used in code. No one can fetch the address of register variable so we can say it is safe also.

Answer (score 7):

"As we know" - actually we *don't* know that.

`register` is a *suggestion* to the compiler, not a requirement. It's rarely needed with the insanely optimising compilers of today. From the current (C11) standard:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier register
>   suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

So it *could* go into a register. It could also go into faster memory, regular memory or even out on disk, or on a server in Inner Mongolia, to punish coders for using unnecessary keywords :-)

You *may* find it useful in compilers that *aren't* quite so smart (perhaps some older, embedded ones, for example) but even, then, you don't *have* to use it - generally, you should forget about it. It's about as useful as `auto`.

By way of example, let's assume a rather "less-than-optimising" compiler that treats every C instruction as a single unit. By that, I mean something like:

```
int x = 1;
x = x + 7;
x = x - 2;
useX (x);
```

will be converted into the assembly (a classic load-store architecture):

```
loadi  r0,  1          ; set r0 to 1
stor   r0,  [x]        ; store to memory

load   r0,  [x]        ; load from memory
addi   r0,  7          ; add 7
stor   r0,  [x]        ; store to memory

load   r0,  [x]        ; load from memory
subi   r0,  2          ; subtract 2
stor   r0,  [x]        ; store to memory

load   r0,  [x]        ; load from memory
call   useX            ; call the function
```

In other words, no optimisation realising that the value is still in `r0` following the addition so there's no need to load it up again.

In such a (brain-dead) compiler, the use of `register` may give efficiencies that would be quite handy. The code:

```
register int x = 1;
x = x + 7;
x = x - 2;
useX (x);
```

may result in better code along the lines of:

```
loadi  r0,  1          ; set r0 to 1
addi   r0,  7          ; add 7
subi   r0,  2          ; subtract 2
call   useX            ; call the function
```

All that stuff, of course, hinges on the compiler and how it uses registers. The code I've given is just a contrived example. As I stated, with modern compilers, it's rarely necessary.

---

Bottom line, in answer to your specific question "is there any situation/application where we **have** to only use register variable and other variable is not useful on such cases?", the answer is no. If it's truly a C compiler, there is no requirement to use the `register` keyword.

Comment: This is a true statement but it doesn't answer the question. I think it should be a comment. In fact, I made a strikingly similar comment...

Comment: It is a requirement if accompanied by an `asm` statement.

Comment: yes you can say suggestion to the compiler and compiler can ignore it also. But i want to know where and why we use, i mean the situation...

Comment: @SK-logic, there is no `asm` keyword in the C core language. Some _implementations_ may provide inline assembly (as per ISO-C appendix J: common extensions) but it's by no means necessary. And, since it's not specified beyond `asm { character-string-literal }` (and that's only a _common_ syntax, not a mandated one), `asm` cannot mandate use of `register`. I could quite easily inject inline assembler that only modified memory, using _no_ registers.

Comment: @paxdiablo, yes, I'm talking of a gcc-specific extension here: I do not know of any other cases when `register` is enforced. But this particular extension is employed by many other compilers as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no situation where you *have to* use `register`. But other than it seems to be urban legend, `register` has a semantic meaning in a C program: variables that are declared with `register` instead of `auto`, the default, can't be subject to `&`, so their address can't be taken. This means that they can never alias with other variables, and thus `register` is merely an optimization hint, just as `restrict`.

Comment: I was wondering if this detail was worth mentioning.  I think it is.

Comment: Great point: "you can't have a pointer to a register variable". Not sure why you would ever care, but it's something that had not crossed my mind before.

Comment: @floris: perhaps someone might want to avoid the optimization-killer mistake of taking the address of a local variable in some time critical code. This might be a way to get the compiler to let you know if you do that.  Maybe you are are concerned that using the variable in a macro might take the address without making it obvious or that code maintenance in the future might let the mistake slip in.  I don't think this is a particularly great example, but I could imagine someone thinking along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

There is a case when it worth not just hinting your compiler to allocate a register for a variable, but name a specific register for it (and then it is not allowed to ignore the `register` keyword): implementing efficient threaded virtual machines.

A nice example of such approach is the [OCaml bytecode interpreter](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/byterun/interp.c).

And in any other case where you have to mix C and assembly code, manually mapping C variables to the registers is essential.

Comment: This is a GCC extension, not part of the normal C language.

Comment: @immibis, nowadays GCC extensions are pretty ubiquitous, implemented by many other compilers as well (Clang, icc).